# Connecting to wifi and ethernet at the same time

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-hole

Device: Raspberry PI 4
OS: Raspberry Pi OS

I have a setup pihole to run on my Raspberry PI with the below network setup.

**Wifi** - Connected to **Guest** Network(Static IP: 192.168.1.56)

**Ethernet** - Connected to **Main** Network(Static IP: 192.168.1.55)

But when ethernet and wifi are connected at the same time my wifi's IP 192.168.1.56, is not available for access for my devices in the guest network. But it is available in the main network.

If I disconnect my ethernet cable my wifi's IP address 192.168.1.56 is available for access by my devices in my guest network.

How can I make my wifi's IP address be available on the guest network when ethernet(on the main network) is connected?

Comment: DO NOT post detail in Comments; edit your Question.

Comment: If you have 1 router you have 1 network (VPN excepted)

Answer (score 1):

You have a conflict in IP addressing. Both subnets are the same, by the looks of it they're both 192.168.1.0/24. You must give one of the two networks a different subnet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My router does not have an option to assign different subnets in the guest and main network. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: If you want to separate the networks, they MUST have different subnets. A router is made for routing between different networks with different subnets and therefore, a router will support this. Or you are trying to do something completely different that you do not describe. And, no, there is no other solution. For the Pi, both interfaces are connected to the same network (192.168.1.0/24) and that is what the Pi sees.

Comment: Well, mine is a TP-Link Deco and it does not seem to have the option of assigning different subnets for main and guest networks.

Comment: And how then do you make any difference between guest and main?

Comment: It is an option in the router to enable a guest wifi network. And devices in the guest wifi network cannot access devices in the main network.